# The use of would in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, modal-verbs

Here Jack uses "would" in his response to the questioner. Could you explain why is "would" used rather than "will?" I would have said "I will add that ..." there because "will" is used to make a decision at the moment of speaking.

> **Goblok**: I want to know the difference in meaning between sentences in the form of "I never knew vs I didn't know." Could you explain?

> *I never knew you were coming vs I didn't know you were coming.*

> **Chez**: it's simply a nuance of meaning.
> "I never knew" expresses surprise and/or emphasis.
> "I didn't know" is just the normal (neutral) negative form.

> **Jack**: I agree with Chez. I **would add** that "I never knew you were coming" doesn't really seem natural, although it's not impossible. "I never knew" works best when it's followed by an action of long duration (or a state like "being so much fun").

Answer (score 0):

"*I would add...*" is a polite way of adding to what someone else has said.

Here, "would" does not express a decision made in the moment.

More generally, the function of "would" here is to convey politeness.

The origin of this function is likely from the use of "would" in *unreal conditional* constructions:

> (If I were to say something,) I would add...

So the politeness comes from the (untrue) implication that you're not really adding anything at all.

Comment: Can I also use "will" in that sentence? "I will add that ..."

Comment: Yes, you can, but it lacks that extra nuance of politeness supplied by _would_.